# How to make fprintf and fflush more effective?

Tags: printf, fflush

I want to write a logger for my server. I am using the `fprintf` function to write a log file.

If my server crashes, then the buffer can't flush, so I can't get the last text from buffer.

If i call `fflush` function after `fprintf` every time, is that a good solution?
Is there any good solution to make my logger more effective?

Comment: It's quite common to flush after write for logging for just the situation you describe. As long as your logging is not excessive and/or not always active, it's no problem.

Comment: Thank you,I will take your suggestion.